# Форма, прием значение и постоянный глобальный вывод

Tags: php, sql

Как мне принять и вывести значение формы которое было передано `POST-Запросом` в `PHP`? У меня есть "голый" хостинг на котором присутствует только `index.html`, ничего стороннего нету. Я хочу добавить форму чтоб форма принимало значение, а затем отображало введенное значение на сервер. Хотел сделать как БД ибо будет много пользователей и уместить в одном файле будет трудно. А затем просто выбирать значения из БД и выводить на экран. Как это реализовать на **PHP + SQL** ?

Comment: Если первая часть вашего вопроса еще может быть понятна. То вторая вряд ли может таким похвастать. Объясните, о чем вы?

Comment: @teran обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, вы хотите получить значение и сохранить его в файл. По коду - сначала получаем значение переменной, создаем/открываем файл, записываем данные, закрываем файл

```
if (!isset($POST['your_value'])) {
    throw new Exception('Данных нет');
}
$yourValue = $POST['your_value'];
$filePointer = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
$isWriteSuccess = fwrite($filePointer, $yourValue);
if (!$isWriteSuccess ) {
    throw new Exception('Запись не удалась');
}
fclose($filePointer );
```

Если нужно использовать SQL - создаете таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE Log (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
comment TEXT
);
```

Тогда код выше превратится в

```
if (!isset($POST['your_value'])) {
    throw new Exception('Данных нет');
}
$yourValue = $POST['your_value'];
//$connectString, $user и $pass - коннекты к бд
$db = new PDO($connectString, $user, $pass);
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO log (comment) VALUES (:comment)");
$query->bindParam(':comment', $yourValue);
$query->execute();
```

И потом получаем данные из таблицы и выводим

```
$selectQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT comment FROM log");
$selectQuery->execute();
$result = $selectQuery->fetchColumn();
echo implode(' ', $result);
```

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли. Изменил вопрос, сделал более информативным и понятным.

Comment: Ругается на Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' в 10 строке, то есть там где обрабатываются исключение.

Comment: скорее всего не в 10 строке, а на 10 позиции в 1 строке. Поправил. Исключение тут не обрабатывается, а только создается

Comment: Dovgopol спасибо, с это ошибкой покончено. Но выскакивает другая ошибка: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No date' in Z:\home\formm.ru\www\handler.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in Z:\home\formm.ru\www\handler.php on line 4 Пользуюсь денвером. Указывает мне на исключение, я просто в пхп полный ноль, ни понимаю что к чему. PHP не сильно хочу учить в дальнейшем, поэтому задаю промежуточные вопросы.